# How to get the current islamic dates record from database using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

I have one javascript file for getting the Islamic Months. im getting the data from sql with the javascript  for the whole current month. I want to get the data from mysql using the same javascript for the Current day only. please help i just can not figure it out. the sources ate pasted below:

:: javascript ::

```
function gmod(n,m){
    return ((n%m)+m)%m;
}

function kuwaiticalendar(adjust){
    var today = new Date();
    if(adjust) {
        adjustmili = 1000*60*60*24*adjust; 
        todaymili = today.getTime()+adjustmili;
        today = new Date(todaymili);
    }
    day = today.getDate();
    month = today.getMonth();
    year = today.getFullYear();
    m = month+1;
    y = year;
    if(m<3) {
        y -= 1;
        m += 12;
    }

    a = Math.floor(y/100.);
    b = 2-a+Math.floor(a/4.);
    if(y<1583) b = 0;
    if(y==1582) {
        if(m>10)  b = -10;
        if(m==10) {
            b = 0;
            if(day>4) b = -10;
        }
    }

    jd = Math.floor(365.25*(y+4716))+Math.floor(30.6001*(m+1))+day+b-1524;

    b = 0;
    if(jd>2299160){
        a = Math.floor((jd-1867216.25)/36524.25);
        b = 1+a-Math.floor(a/4.);
    }
    bb = jd+b+1524;
    cc = Math.floor((bb-122.1)/365.25);
    dd = Math.floor(365.25*cc);
    ee = Math.floor((bb-dd)/30.6001);
    day =(bb-dd)-Math.floor(30.6001*ee);
    month = ee-1;
    if(ee>13) {
        cc += 1;
        month = ee-13;
    }
    year = cc-4716;

    if(adjust) {
        wd = gmod(jd+1-adjust,7)+1;
    } else {
        wd = gmod(jd+1,7)+1;
    }

    iyear = 10631./30.;
    epochastro = 1948084;
    epochcivil = 1948085;

    shift1 = 8.01/60.;

    z = jd-epochastro;
    cyc = Math.floor(z/10631.);
    z = z-10631*cyc;
    j = Math.floor((z-shift1)/iyear);
    iy = 30*cyc+j;
    z = z-Math.floor(j*iyear+shift1);
    im = Math.floor((z+28.5001)/29.5);
    if(im==13) im = 12;
    id = z-Math.floor(29.5001*im-29);

    var myRes = new Array(8);

    myRes[0] = day; //calculated day (CE)
    myRes[1] = month-1; //calculated month (CE)
    myRes[2] = year; //calculated year (CE)
    myRes[3] = jd-1; //julian day number
    myRes[4] = wd-1; //weekday number
    myRes[5] = id; //islamic date
    myRes[6] = im-1; //islamic month
    myRes[7] = iy; //islamic year

    return myRes;
}
function writeIslamicDate(adjustment) {
    var wdNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
    var iMonthNames = new Array("Muharram-ul-Haram","Safar-ul-Muzaffar","Rabi-ul-Awwal","Rabi-us-Sani","Jumad-al-Awwal","Jumad-as-Sani","Rajab-ul-Murajjab","Shaban-ul-Muazzam","Ramadan-ul-Mubarak","Shawwal-ul-Mukarram","Zeeqada-tul-Haram","Zulhijja-tul-Haram");
    var iDate = kuwaiticalendar(adjustment);
    var outputIslamicDate = wdNames[iDate[4]] + ", " 
    + iDate[5] + " " + iMonthNames[iDate[6]] + " " + iDate[7] + " AH";
    return outputIslamicDate;
}

function writeIslamicMonthID(adjustment) {
    var iMonthNames = new Array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
    var iDate = kuwaiticalendar(adjustment);
    var outputIslamicDate = iMonthNames[iDate[6]];
    return outputIslamicDate;
}
```

:: PHP ::

```
<?php $current_month_id = $_GET["current-month-id"]; ?>
<?php $current_idate_id = $_GET["current-idate-id"]; ?>


   <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","");
mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE month ='$current_month_id' AND day ='$current_idate_id' ");



echo "<marquee id=marMessages dir=rtl onmouseover=this.scrollAmount=0 onmouseout=this.scrollAmount=2 scrollAmount=2 direction=up width='95%' height='112'>
<p align='Left'>

";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($display))
      {

    echo "<div>";
    echo "<ul class='arr-three-list'>";
    echo "<li>";    
    echo "{$row['n_namest']}";
    echo "</li></ul></div> <br>";

      }

echo "</p></marquee>";


    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: i am not getting your question, you are having issue querying days data or unable to fire an event to get data? probably you need to join the tables to get data, if you could show your table structure may be we could help.

Comment: well i found this Kuwait calendar javascript on google and its showing date fine... even when i try to get the Books By Month its showing without any problem. but when i apply the query to display the Books Of The Current Day or Event Of The Day then it doesnt work ???

Comment: i do have the field of cmonths_id & cday_id in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is below:

```
function gmod(n,m){
    return ((n%m)+m)%m;
}

function kuwaiticalendar(adjust){
    var today = new Date();
    if(adjust) {
        adjustmili = 1000*60*60*24*adjust; 
        todaymili = today.getTime()+adjustmili;
        today = new Date(todaymili);
    }
    day = today.getDate();
    month = today.getMonth();
    year = today.getFullYear();
    m = month+1;
    y = year;
    if(m<3) {
        y -= 1;
        m += 12;
    }

    a = Math.floor(y/100.);
    b = 2-a+Math.floor(a/4.);
    if(y<1583) b = 0;
    if(y==1582) {
        if(m>10)  b = -10;
        if(m==10) {
            b = 0;
            if(day>4) b = -10;
        }
    }

    jd = Math.floor(365.25*(y+4716))+Math.floor(30.6001*(m+1))+day+b-1524;

    b = 0;
    if(jd>2299160){
        a = Math.floor((jd-1867216.25)/36524.25);
        b = 1+a-Math.floor(a/4.);
    }
    bb = jd+b+1524;
    cc = Math.floor((bb-122.1)/365.25);
    dd = Math.floor(365.25*cc);
    ee = Math.floor((bb-dd)/30.6001);
    day =(bb-dd)-Math.floor(30.6001*ee);
    month = ee-1;
    if(ee>13) {
        cc += 1;
        month = ee-13;
    }
    year = cc-4716;

    if(adjust) {
        wd = gmod(jd+1-adjust,7)+1;
    } else {
        wd = gmod(jd+1,7)+1;
    }

    iyear = 10631./30.;
    epochastro = 1948084;
    epochcivil = 1948085;

    shift1 = 8.01/60.;

    z = jd-epochastro;
    cyc = Math.floor(z/10631.);
    z = z-10631*cyc;
    j = Math.floor((z-shift1)/iyear);
    iy = 30*cyc+j;
    z = z-Math.floor(j*iyear+shift1);
    im = Math.floor((z+28.5001)/29.5);
    if(im==13) im = 12;
    id = z-Math.floor(29.5001*im-29);

    var myRes = new Array(8);

    myRes[0] = day; //calculated day (CE)
    myRes[1] = month-1; //calculated month (CE)
    myRes[2] = year; //calculated year (CE)
    myRes[3] = jd-1; //julian day number
    myRes[4] = wd-1; //weekday number
    myRes[5] = id; //islamic date
    myRes[6] = im-1; //islamic month
    myRes[7] = iy; //islamic year

    return myRes;
}

//COMPLETE DATE
function writeIslamicDate(adjustment) {
    var wdNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
    var iMonthNames = new Array("Muharram-ul-Haram","Safar-ul-Muzaffar","Rabi-ul-Awwal","Rabi-us-Sani","Jumad-al-Awwal","Jumad-as-Sani","Rajab-ul-Murajjab","Shaban-ul-Muazzam","Ramadan-ul-Mubarak","Shawwal-ul-Mukarram","Zeeqada-tul-Haram","Zulhijja-tul-Haram");
    var eMonthNames = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
    var iDate = kuwaiticalendar(adjustment);
    var outputIslamicDate = wdNames[iDate[4]] + ", " + iDate[5] + " " + iMonthNames[iDate[6]] + " " + iDate[7] + " AH";
    return outputIslamicDate;
}
//ONLY MONTH
function writeIslamicMonthID(adjustment) {
    var iMonthNames = new Array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
    var iDate = kuwaiticalendar(adjustment);
    var outputIslamicMonth = iMonthNames[iDate[6]];
    return outputIslamicMonth;
}
//ONLY DATE
function writeIslamicDayID(adjustment) {
    var iMonthNames = new Array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30");
    var iDate = kuwaiticalendar(adjustment);
    var outputIslamicDay = iDate[5];
    return outputIslamicDay;
}
```

Comment: i did this a month ago but forget to post it here so others can get benefit of this.